# Gradle dependency issue, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, but compiles

Tags: java, exception, gradle, build

new to gradle and java here and I am trying to use Android's Log method from android.util.Log.  It seems I can compile and it finds what it needs, but it can not find it at runtime.  I have tried using 'runtime' instead of 'compile' in the dependencies section, but not luck.

```
java -jar build/libs/testJavaHttp.jar

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/util/Log
        at myproject.test.HttpToFile.downloadFile(HttpToFile.java:20)
        at myproject.test.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.util.Log
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 2 more
```

---

### In build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile files('../androidsdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar')
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'myproject.test.Main'
    }
}
```

Comment: Your IDE can compile, but your Gradle cannot, because you didn't specify your classpath

Comment: not using an IDE

Comment: you can check [this link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_source_sets)

Comment: appears to be used, here is the build debug msg.  note the classpath.... 18:41:36.330 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler] Compiler arguments: -source 1.8 -target 1.8 -d /Users/myname/dev/testJavaHttp/build/classes/main -g -sourcepath  -proc:none -XDuseUnsharedTable=true -classpath /Users/myname/dev/androidsdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar /Users/myname/dev/testJavaHttp/src/main/java/myproject/test/HttpToFile.java /Users/myname/dev/testJavaHttp/src/main/java/myproject/test/Main.java

Comment: adding 
attributes 'Class-Path': '../androidsdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar'
doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run the jar and the jar is not packed with dependencies, use shadow jar plugin or pack required artifacts in, by extending the jar task.

```
jar {
    archiveName = 'Name.jar'

    manifest {
         attributes 'Main-Class': 'myproject.test.Main',
                'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' '),
                'Implementation-Version': 1.0
    }

    from(configurations.myconfig.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {
           // in here you can exclude what you need as well if needed.
           }
}
```

To not pull the 'entire world' into a jar you can create configuration just with libraries you require:

```
configurations{
    myconfig // to create configuration
    compile.extendsFrom(myConfig) //to include it in compile as well
}
```

and then use this config in the jar creation and in dependecies.

```
dependencies {
    myconfig files('../androidsdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar')
}
```

But looking at your code there is not much to pull there. You need to consider packing all needed artifacts and transitives if you expect it to be a runnable jar, as you run it with 'java -jar [...]' command.

PS. Everything that is in compile is going to be included in runtime configuration as well.

Comment: gives me.  
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
        at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:23)
        at myproject.test.HttpToFile.downloadFile(HttpToFile.java:20)
        at myproject.test.Main.main(Main.java:12)

Comment: this also seems to pull in the entire world into the jar

Comment: the error you getting now is a different error, probably your code problem, the problem you have posted should by fix by solution I proposed you can investigate further what and why it fails in your main. I have updated the answer to give an example of not pulling 'the entire world' into the jar.